# Difference between Full Page catch(FPC) and Magento inbuilt caching in Magento

Tags: magento, caching

1. What is difference between *Full Page Catch* (FPC) and Magento inbuilt caching?
2. Why we use FPC when already a caching system is available in Magento?
3. Which one is preferable?

Comment: Both are preferable. The Magento Cache assembles the blocks themselves that make up the page, the FPC delivers the whole assembly all bolted together. It's basically two separate levels running in tandem to deliver more speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With FPC complete page is cached and hole punching(container) system where by containers are replaced with complete html if needed.

In simple cache system blocks are cached and only blocks are checked if there cache exist.

with FPC on times application will not be initialized but complete page might be delivered from FPC which is not the case with normal block caching.